# Positive and Invertible Operator Implies Strictly Positive

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

A similar question was asked but I'm wondering about the other direction.
Let $T\in B(\mathcal{H})$ be invertible and positive ($\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space). I'm trying to prove/disprove the existence of some $c>0$ such that $\langle Th,h\rangle\geq c\lVert h\rVert^2$ for all $h\in\mathcal{H}$.

It seems to me as if it's nessecarily true - since if I'm trying to think of an operator which causes a problem, I think of some $T$ and a series of $h_n\in\mathcal{H}$ of norm $1$ such that $\langle Th_n,h_n\rangle\to 0$. But every example I could think of for such an operator, was actually compact and thus non-invertible.

Next, I thought of "rotations" which are invertible but the $T$ wouldn't be positive.

So my intuition is that it is actually true, but I'm kind of stuck.

I did manage to prove the other way around, meaning the if we can find such $c$, that $T$ is invertible and positive.

Comment: If "invertible" means that $T$ has a bounded inverse, then such a $c$ exists.

Comment: Yes it is what I meant. I got stuck in trying to prove it's existence.

Comment: Can we use the fact that $T$ has a positive square root $T^{1/2}$?

Comment: I think that the square root was not yet defined at the time this excercise was given. Maybe for a positive and compact operator.

Answer (score 3):

Because $T$ is positive, the form $[h,k]=\langle Th,k\rangle$ is positive and so it satisfies Cauchy-Schwarz. Then
\begin{align}
\|h\|^2
&=\langle h,h\rangle =[T^{-1}h,h]\\[0.3cm]
&\leq [T^{-1}h,T^{-1}h]^{1/2}[h,h]^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&=\langle h,T^{-1}h\rangle ^{1/2}\langle Th,h\rangle^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq \|h\|\,\|T^{-1}\|^{1/2}\,\langle Th,h\rangle^{1/2}.
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\|T^{-1}\|^{-1}\,\|h\|^2\leq \langle Th,h\rangle.$$